# Example with Grep4j 1.5 version (for jdk 1.5)

Tags: java, xml

I need to find if any of several strings of my List exist in a List of files with extension .txt and .xml.

I have my own list of strings: `"hello"`,`"goodbye"`,`"etc"`.

I need the list of files with `"hello"` or `"goodbye"` or `"etc"`.

For example:

```
a.csv contains:
a|b|hello|d

b.xml contains:
<a>
 <b></b>
 <c>goodbye</c>
</a>
```

The List of files in this case are:

```
/path/folder1/a.csv
/path/folder2/b.xml
```

And then, renombrate with folder name:

```
/path/folder1/a.csv.folder1
/path/folder2/b.xml.folder2
```

Comment: are those files remote or locals?

Comment: they are in local server...

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a list of files with a specific word in it you can do something like :

```
Profile remoteProfile = ProfileBuilder.newBuilder()
        .name("Remote folder1")
        .filePath("/path/folder1/*")
        .onRemotehost("172.xx.xx.xx")
        .credentials("user", "password")
        .build();


System.out.println(grep(constantExpression("hello"),on(remoteProfile),with(option(filesMatching()))));
```

see https://code.google.com/p/grep4j/wiki/ProfileWithWildcard for details